# JAVA Unitialised objects after try-catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I am struggling with this code of try and catch block. What can I do to have the object initialized as in try catch block after that block? I know that after the try catch, the object values will be destroyed , but still , is there any way I can have them initialized after that block ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Error {
            Person p1=null;Person p2=null;
            Student s1=null;Student s2=null;
            Employe a=null;
            try{
            p1 = new Person("Zeer", "Sohn", 1.7,2, 100); //Name , surname,height,age
            p2 = new Person("Zeer", "Mike", 1.63, 39);
            s1 = new Student("Johnson", "John", 1.9, 21, 2, 1);
            s2 = new Student("Deer", "Son", 1.52, 20, 1, 1);
            a = new Employe("Stewie", "Michael", 1.74, 44, 12, 440);

            }catch (Error.ErrorHeight e){

                System.out.println("Error height:"+e.getMessage());
            }catch (Error.ErrorAge e){
                System.out.println("Error age: "+e.getMessage());
            }catch (Error.ErrorSalary e){
                System.out.println("Error salary"+e.getMessage());
            } catch (Error e) {
                System.out.println("General error"+e.getMessage());

            };

            Person []p={p1,p2,s1,s2,a};

            for (Person i : p)
                System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Sort:");
            c = new Comparator<Person>() {
                public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {

                    return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();

                }
            };
            Arrays.sort(p, c);
```

Comment: Have you declared the exception: `Error.ErrorHeight`, `Error.ErrorAge` etc? Is some of your classes supposed to throw them? And when you say initialize it does not make sense: initialize means give value for the first time. Maybe you meant assign? Be more specific of what you want

Comment: Yes, assign is what i want . I want those object to have the same value as there after the try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that after the try catch , the object values will be destroyed.

Yes. When the variable of the created object excits the scope in which it was created, the object will be claimed by the garbage collector. If you want it to remain alive, you declare the variables outside the try block, just like you did in:

```
        Person p1=null;Person p2=null;
        Student s1=null;Student s2=null;
```

However, if one or more of those objects thros an exception, the initialisation will not complete and those objects will revert back to null. You can give it default values before the try block. Or just initialise it outside the try block.

Answer (score 1):

The values of p1,p2,s1,s2 and a will not be destroyed after the try-catch block. However, is an exception is thrown in the try block, some of them may remain uninitialized.

If you want to rely on the values of those variables even after an exception is thrown and caught, you must give them some default values either in the catch blocks or in a finally block (assuming you can't just give them a default value before the try-catch block).

Comment: I placed this in the finally block :p1 = new Person("Zeer", "Sohn", 1.7,2, 100); 
            p2 = new Person("Zeer", "Mike", 1.63, 39);
            s1 = new Student("Johnson", "John", 1.9, 21, 2, 1);
            s2 = new Student("Deer", "Son", 1.52, 20, 1, 1);
            a = new Employe("Stewie", "Michael", 1.74, 44, 12, 440);
and this line : Person []p={p1,p2,s1,s2,a}; says that those p1,p2,s1,s2,a cant be resolved to a variable

Comment: @aNNgeL0 If the code you posted in your question is the same code you are compiling, this is not possible, since p1,p2,s1,s2 & a are all declare before the try-catch block, so they are still visible after it.

Comment: @aNNgeL0 BTW, if one of the constructor calls in the try block throws an exception, running the same code in the finally code would also throw an exception, so this solves nothing.